# How exactly does migration work?

Tags: discussion, migration

I'm still a little confused on how the whole process works.  What and how determines whether or not a question gets migrated, and where it goes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you vote to close a question as Off Topic, you are given the choice of voting to migrate it to another site. THe options availiable vary by SE site, and are determined by Mods/Admins. In the case of Arqade, the only availiable migration path of this sort is to Meta. If more than 3 close votes suggest migration to the same place, the question is migrated.

Additionally, Moderators can migrate a question to any other Stack Exchange site. This is not done often, and ideally, only after consulting with the mods or community of the destination site, to avoid rejected migrations.

Comment: I've seen a few questions closed every now and then that would probably belong on GameDev, is there a reason we don't provide a migration path there?

Comment: Mods can still migrate to GameDev at their discretion. There's no path because it would be minimally useful and easily misused/abused.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks